# Changing Title Tag on Shop Archive Page (current solution reverting to Title of First Product in Loop)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, title, get-the-title

Firstly, `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` is enabled in my theme.

I have two filters to modify titles, this one hooking on to `the_title`

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_account_endpoint_titles', 10, 2 );
function custom_account_endpoint_titles( $title ) {

// Currently only have conditions here for My Account pages (is_account_page())
// example: if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['edit-account'] ) && is_account_page() ) {    

return $title;
}
```

Secondly I have another function which fixed some title issues on Account pages as well (if I do not add this, the My Account pages all revert to a title tag of simply `My Account` instead of the conditional statements set for the Title changed intended.

```
function theme_slug_filter_wp_title( $title_parts ) {
        $title_parts['title'] = get_the_title();
    return $title_parts;
}

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title' );
```

Doing a little debugging -- adding a `print_r` on `$title_parts` in the `document_title_parts` function

```
<pre>Array
(
    [title] => Products
    [site] => Example.com
)
</pre>
```

One would think, that the Title on my Shop Archive page would just be `Products`, but that is not the case.

Doing the same `print_r` debugging on the `the_title` filter on my shop archive page...

brings back `<pre>925 Sterling Silver.....</pre>` (which is the name of the first product in the loop

followed by `<pre>Shop</pre>` for the breadcrumb

and then additionally above all my products in the shop archive, the title and a list of classes, but te html seems to be malformed when doing so which is odd:

```
<div class="grid_col">    <div <pre="">925 Sterling Silver...... class="shop-product hover-border nt-post-class masonry-item excerpt-none product type-product "
```

The only solution I have read which does not work is hooking onto the `is_shop()` function in my `the_title` filter, such as..

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_account_endpoint_titles', 10, 2 );
function custom_account_endpoint_titles( $title ) {
    global $wp_query;
    global $current_user;

    if (is_shop()) {
        return 'My Shop Archive';
    }
```

This does indeed change the `<title>` tag on the shop page to `My Shop Archive`... but then proceeds to change the title of all my products on the page to `My Shop Archive`!

[image]

What is the solution for just simply changing the `<title>` tag on my shops archive page without affecting the product titles like in the image above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the solution I was looking for was `!in_the_loop()`

Full:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_account_endpoint_titles', 10, 2 );
function custom_account_endpoint_titles( $title ) {
if (is_shop() && !in_the_loop() && ! is_admin() && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX )) {
    return 'Shop - Parure.co';
}
}
```

Note: the `!is_admin` and `!DOING_AJAX` functions are to prevent this from affecting product titles in the admin panel